# \int_incr:N inside tabular environment

Tags: tables, expl3

I started learning LaTeX3 a few weeks ago and I'm currently playing around with tables. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \juhu_tablerow:n #1
{
  \int_new:N \l_row_count_int
  \int_set:Nn \l_row_count_int { 1 }
  \prg_replicate:nn {#1}
  {
    \int_use:N \l_row_count_int .~row \\
    \int_incr:N \l_row_count_int
  }
}
\cs_new_eq:NN \tablerow \juhu_tablerow:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
\tablerow{3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The output of this code is:

```
1. row
1. row
1. row
```

The desired output should be like this:

```
1. row
2. row
3. row
```

When I replace the `tabular` environment e.g. with a `center` environment, I get the expected output.

Now, if I replace the `\\` in `\int_use:N \l_row_count_int .~row \\` with `,~`, `\int_incr:N` seems to work again even inside the `tabular` environment, and the output is:

```
1. row, 2. row, 3. row,
```

So, my question is, why increasing the integer doesn't work inside a `tabular` environment when using multiple rows, and what can I do to get the desired result?

Comment: I think you should change the scope assignment from local to global. Then things work. `:)` *Edit:* Oh, and move the integer declaration outside your command too. `:)`

Comment: Also, [welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @PauloCereda sounds like a draft for an answer :)

Comment: @PauloCereda Your comment solved my problem. Thank you! If you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>From my humble comment to an answer. `:)`</sup>

You were very close to a solution! The culprit here is the scope: those assignments are happening locally; let us make them global.

Before we proceed, we must move the integer declaration outside your command definition, otherwise an error will be raised in subsequent calls to `\tablerow`. Now, a little coding convention, from

```
\int_new:N \l_row_count_int
```

to

```
\int_new:N \g_row_count_int
```

since our counter became global. `:)` Now, a couple of replacements (thanks to egreg for the `xparse` suggestion!):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \g_row_count_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \juhu_tablerow:n #1
{
  \int_gset:Nn \g_row_count_int { 1 }
  \prg_replicate:nn {#1}
  {
    \int_use:N \g_row_count_int .~row \\
    \int_gincr:N \g_row_count_int
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{ \tablerow }{ m }{
    \juhu_tablerow:n{#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
\tablerow{3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And everything should be working just fine. `:)`

You could also go with `\g_tmpa_int` which is a scratch integer for global assignment and save a couple of bucks. `:)`

Comment: I'd just replace the `\cs_new_eq:NN` line with `\NewDocumentCommand{\tablerow}{m}{\juhu_tablerow:n{#1}}` (loading `xparse`, of course).